# Yii GridView Ajax update not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii, cgridview

I have a page that contains CGridView in my app. Users can search data by filling the form and clicking submit button. The search function works, and CGridView successfully updated. The problem is it can't be done through ajax, Yii keep doing it through parameters in URL.

I want to update CGridView through ajax so the URL still nice to look. Here's my code.

View File

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
    $('.btn-link').click(function(){
            $('.section').toggle();
            return false;
    });

    $('.section form').submit(function(){
    $('#customer2-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });

    return false;
    });
");
?>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'btn-link')); ?>

<div class="section" style="display:none">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    )); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'customer2-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'font-weight:bold'),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(

        'NAME',
        'BIRTHDATE',
        'ADDRESS',
        'EMAIL',

        array(
            'header'=>'Action',
                        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template' => '{add} {updates}',
                        'buttons' => array(
                                    'add' => array(
                                        'label' => '',
                                        //'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/icon/add.png',
                                        'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/goods/create/",array("id"=>$data->ID))',
                                        'options'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-info', 'style'=> 'margin-bottom:2px  '),
                                         ),

                                      'updates' => array(
                                          'label' => 'Update Profil',
                                         // 'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/icon/update.png',
                                          'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/customer/update/",array("id"=>$data->ID))',
                                          'options'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-info'),
                                          ),    


                         ),
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

Here's my _search.php code

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method'=>'get',
)); ?>



    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'NAME',array('class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'NAME',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128,'class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'BIRTHDATE',array('class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'BIRTHDATE',array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ADDRESS',array('class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'ADDRESS',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>512,'class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'EMAIL',array('class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'EMAIL',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>64,'class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>


<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- search-form -->
```

Here's my controller code

```
public function actionAdmin()
    {       
                $this->layout = '//layouts/column1';
        $model=new Customer('search');

        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Customer']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Customer'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

The toggle function in the jQuery works just fine but the update function doesn't work. The sorting function in CGridView works as well. What do I miss here?

Is there any restriction in CSS for jQuery/CGridView? I presume there's something wrong with the CSS Selector

**EDIT :**
I've found the problem which unexpectedly lies in `layout/main.php`
I've included three javascript files and one of them causing the error.

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/default/js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY UI-->
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/default/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/default/bootstrap-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

After I discarded the first script, everything's fine. However, I don't have idea why. Maybe somebody can explain why. Any explanation will be appreciated. Sorry if this question going out of topic

Comment: why you did not use filter property of CGridView?

Comment: filter property also doesn't work. I have no idea why. Does this have something to do with the model?

Comment: you must specify filter property as model
    'filter' => $model,

Comment: @Panoptik I did and it doesn't work, the same as ajax searching

Comment: Yii declare jquery script automatically when you call CGridView widget
so you may obtain 2 or more declared jquery on page.
Scripts position is important, and when you redeclared jquery script  all existing jquery handlers at page lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I try to describe common solution

this code exampling with default gii crud generator

let you have model Customer.php generetad with standard gii module

```
class Customer extends CActiveRecord 
{
    // ...

    public function search() {
        return new CActiveDataProvider(
            // provider properties
            'criteria' => new CDbCriteria(), // searches and filters
            'sort' => new CSort(), //  ordering
            'pagination' => new CPagination(), //  pagging
        );
    }

    // also there are exists rules for search scneario

    public function rules() {
        return array(
            // ... some other rules

            // rule for scenario search
            array('NAME, BIRTHDATE,ADDRESS, EMAIL', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

next we should describe primitive controller

```
class CustomerController extends CController 
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // create model with scenario search
        $model = new Customer('search');

        // check for incoming filter requests and apply filter
        if(isset($_GET['Customer']) {
            $model->attributes = $_GET['Customer'];
        }

        $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model);
    }
}
```

now we have to create simplest view with basic CGridView settings

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
          'provider' => $model->search(),
          // this property automatically add search field above each columns
          'filter' => $model,

      ));
```

try this code. and you no need to invent already existing solution by specifying custom search form, of course if you want to have extended search tools, you have to some hard codding

Comment: Thanks so much, it's not the solution but after following what you describe and rewrite some code, i find the problem